# GWT Import Class and net.sf.jsonJSONObject

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I have 2 classes both in the same package. The initial compile and build was fine without any issues. Not due to requirements I am creating an object for class B in class A like.

```
    Class A {
    int a;
    Sting b;
    B b;

    .. all getters and setters..
}


import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
Class B {
..do JSON activities..
}
```

Both classes DO NOT have a gwt.xml and are not in the presentation layer. The client side classes and gwt xml are in a separate package. They are in the same package.
Now the build works when the class B object in class A is removed. When we have the object in the class, I get the error

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:......./domain/ExecutorResponse.java'
[ERROR] Line 73: No source code is available for type net.sf.json.JSONObject; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Unable to find type '....ReleaseReportModule'          
[ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
```

My POM has the dependency mapped. The build was working till now. It is failing only recently after the addition of the object. I also tried adding `<inherit... >` in the parent gwt xml that uses these class objects, but with no luck.

What could possibly be the issue here?

My package structure is

```
src/main/java
|
|--com.my.pack.helper
    |
    |--both my classes are here
|
|--com.my.pack.gwt
    |
    |--contains client side classes with UIObjects and Widgets. Helper objects used here to populate the data.





src/main/resources
|
|--com.my.pack.gwt
    |
    |--widgets
        |
        |--contains the ui.xml & gwt.xml
    |
    |--common.gwt.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest to use [gwt-jsonwrapper](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-jsonwrapper/) in client side. If you still willing to use [net.sf.json](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/package-summary.html), use only in server side of your GWT project and return values as String format via RPC.

```
public final String getSomething() {
   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
   Bean bean = .....;
   obj = JSONObject.fromObject(bean);
   return StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(obj.toString());
}
```

At your client side, parse result string as

```
    HTML html = new HTML(result.replace("&nbsp;", "-"));
    JSONValue value = JSONParser.parseLenient(html.getText());
    JSONWrapper json = new JSONWrapper(value);
    JSONWrapper data = json.get("key");
```

For using [gwt-jsonwrapper](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-jsonwrapper/) , add below two line in your module.xml

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.json.JSON"/>
<inherits name='com.pathf.gwt.util.json.jsonwrapper'/>
```

Comment: After a lot of trials I ended removing the net.sf.json dependency and replacing it with the gwt.json. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to use the `net.sf.json.JSONObject` class on the client side, and gwt **doesn't know** how to translate that to javascript.

See [this list](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) for supported classes on client side.

Comment: I have 2 classes. The `Executor` already has the JSON import. It builds and compiles fine. The `Certificate` is a bean class, containing getters and setters for its objects. It does not have any logic written in it. It is just a bean class. Now I am trying to add the `Executor` object as member of the `Certificate` class. Without this member it compiles properly. As stated, one class has the import already and works. The other is jus a bean class. Can you pls explain on how this affects the client side? None of these are linked directly to the client side.

Comment: AFAIK client and server side are based on package used for the class

Comment: added package structure to the question. Can you please look into it and let me know. Also as mentioned in the structure there are currently classes in the gwt package that use the classes in helper package. The are all working fine. I am having an issue only with the JSON import that too with these two specific classes as mentioned previously. And thanks a lot for taking time in helping me out.